# Woocommerce : how to display custom success notice message on Logout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On Logout display success message.
this is my code that i tried.but i don't get success message on logout

this is my code that i tried.but i don't get success message on logout

```
function displaynotice() {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'custom_notice' );
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'displaynotice');

function custom_notice() {
    wc_add_notice( 'This is a Success notice', 'success' );
}
```

I think when I logout, Wordpress or Woocommerce destroys the current session. So all my flash messages would also get destroyed or unset. So using session would not be an option.

**Working solution**

in function.php

```
setcookie('done', null, -1, '/');
add_action('wp_logout',function(){
   setcookie("done", "done", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
});
```

and in the page where we want to show the message

```
<?php 
if(isset($_COOKIE["done"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["done"]) ) {?>
    <div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">
    You've been logged out successfully.</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i think when i logout . word press or woocommerce destroy all sessions. so all my flash message also  destory or unset .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution

in function.php

```
setcookie('done', null, -1, '/');
add_action('wp_logout',function(){
   setcookie("done", "done", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
});
```

and in the page where we want to show the message

```
<?php 
if(isset($_COOKIE["done"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["done"]) ) {?>
    <div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">
    You've been logged out successfully.</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try using `wp_logout` action hook, because whenever the user logs out this hook is called and you should add your logout method to this hook.

example :

```
add_action('wp_logout',function(){
    wc_add_notice( 'This is a Success notice', 'success' );
});
```